# EmitCalli .net core alternative

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, unmanaged, .net-core

Is there any alternative to .net framework EmitCalli for netcoreapp1.0

```
if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, ptr.ToInt32());
else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, ptr.ToInt64()); 

il.EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli, CallingConvention.Cdecl, returnType, paramTypes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EmitCalli will be avaiable in .NET Core 2.1.0-preview2+

Answer (score 4):

Does this library contain what you want?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration/

It contains the System.Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator type, including the function

`EmitCalli(OpCode opcode, CallingConventions callingConvention, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type[] optionalParameterTypes)`

Comment: CallingConventions are different, it's missing Cdecl.

Comment: It does seem like there is potentially a feature gap here, depending on how the native function you are trying to call is declared. I filed an issue on our repository to track this gap: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9800

Comment: Fixed in this PR - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/15040

It still needs to be exposed from the contracts as per https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9800#issuecomment-344797679

I'm looking at this too